# What's the meaning of the parameter "step=1" in pyint from Faker?

Tags: python, parameters, optional-parameters, faker

I'm using the Faker Generator for Python (last version) but still trying to figure out the meaning of the paramater "step=1". Any ideas? There is nothing about this parameter in the documentation or anywhere else on the web so far.

```
pyint(min_value=0, max_value=9999, **step=1**)
```

Link to the page : Click [here](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers/faker.providers.python.html?highlight=pyint#faker.providers.python.Provider.pyint)

Thank you much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pyint` generates a random number effectively sampled from `range(min_value, max_value+1, step)`. That's where the `step` comes in.

The documentation for `pyint` is severely lacking, but if we go to the [source code](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/v8.10.1/faker/providers/python/__init__.py#L149):

```
def pyint(self, min_value=0, max_value=9999, step=1):
    return self.generator.random_int(min_value, max_value, step=step)
```

we see that it delegates to [this method](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/v8.10.1/faker/providers/__init__.py#L104):

```
def random_int(self, min=0, max=9999, step=1):
    """Generate a random integer between two integers ``min`` and ``max`` inclusive
    while observing the provided ``step`` value.
    This method is functionally equivalent to randomly sampling an integer
    from the sequence ``range(min, max + 1, step)``.
    :sample:
    :sample size=10: min=0, max=15
    :sample size=10: min=0, max=15, step=3
    """
    return self.generator.random.randrange(min, max + 1, step)
```

which has a useful docstring.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping and make me realize that this kind of answers might lie in the source code.